# Changing a jqgrid row layout with html tags possible?

Tags: jqgrid

I am using jqgrid responsive bootstrap version in my web application and have no problems.

is it possible to format a row in jqgrid as an html table having 2 rows.

for example lets say I have the fallowing data:

columnn-1 : 20 characters long.
columnn-2 : 20 characters long.
columnn-3 : 200 characters long max (textarea with vertical scroll bar)

is it  possible to display such data as we did in html table with colspan like bellow by using custom formatters in a jqgrid row ?

```
<table border="1">
    <tr>
        <td align='center'>Column-1</td>
        <td align='center'>Column-2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2" align='center'>Column-3</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

[table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7uWTw.jpg)

Thank you.

Comment: Which version of jqGrid is used - commercial [Guriddo jqGrid](http://www.guriddo.net), [free-jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid) or jqGrid <= 4.7?

Comment: Guriddo jqGrid is used.

Comment: What is your datatype (server, local, JSON, xml) and how look the source data that comes to the grid? Do you plan to use this type of the grid for editing and searching or only for displaying?

Comment: Data type is local and in JSON array format,I plan to use the grid just for display purposes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code below make what you want. Please note the use of afterInserRow event and gridview parameter set to false:

```
    var mynewdata = [
        {id: "id1", Col1 : "data11", Col2: "data12", Col3: "data13"},
        {id: "id2", Col1 : "data21", Col2: "data22", Col3: "data23"},
        {id: "id3", Col1 : "data31", Col2: "data32", Col3: "data33"},
        {id: "id4", Col1 : "data41", Col2: "data42", Col3: "data43"}
    ];

    $(document).ready(function () {
       $("#jqGrid").jqGrid({
            datatype: "local",
            data: mynewdata,
            height: 250,
            width: 780,
            colModel: [
                { name: 'id', hidden: true, key: true},
                { name: 'Col1', width: 75 },
                { name: 'Col2', width: 90 },
                { name: 'Col3', width: 100, hidden: true }
            ],          
            gridview : false,
            afterInsertRow: function(id, rowdata, curr) {
                var newid = id+"1";
                var data = '<tr role="row" id="'+newid+'" tabindex="-1" class="jqgrow ui-row-ltr ui-widget-content">';
                data += '<td colspan="2" role="gridcell" style="text-align:center" title="data11" aria-describedby="jqGrid_Col1">'+rowdata.Col3+'</td>';
                data += '</tr>';
                $("#"+id).parent().append(data);
            }
        });
});
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, altough your solution requires an  id field in the data. I will arrange my data accordingly to include an id field.